# Can some stimulants take the place of others?

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology, brain

I learned in class recently that neuroreceptors can cause different chemical changes in the brain and nervous system. I was told that stimulants increase heart rate and awareness, which got me thinking how  different strengths of stimulants might interact with each other. I have been taking medicine for a while now, (methylphenidate), and I have noticed that whenever I drink coffee while the medicine is still in effect, I feel more tired.

So now the question: Since the medicine I take is a stronger stimulant than the caffeine from the coffee, could the caffeine neuroreceptors be taking the place of my medicine (the stronger stimulant) and be making me more tired than I would be if I did not drink coffee, or could it be because of some other reason?

I just want to end this by saying that the knowledge I have of neurochemistry is baseline and I am in no way an expert, so I apologize if this question seems silly to someone who is more informed on this subject.

Comment: This question has a discussion of the specific combination you're asking about: https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/3688/what-is-wrong-with-taking-coffee-and-methylphenidate-together